# Mouse.DirectlyOver working incorrectly when mouse with pressed left button is dragged out

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, window

When mouse is *rapidly* dragged out of the window with **left button pressed** `Mouse.DirectlyOver` returns `System.Windows.Controls.Grid` instead of `null`.

`Window.IsMouseOver` returns `true`

`new Rect(window.RenderSize).Contains(Mouse.GetPosition(window))` returns `true`

To reproduce that, simply add checking timer to `MainWindow()` in a blank wpf project like that:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(state =>
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
                () => Debug.WriteLine("Mouse.DirectlyOver = {0}", Mouse.DirectlyOver)
                )),null,0,10);
    }
```

When i drag out *slowly*, the values are correct.

Is there a workaround for that? What is the coorect way to determine mouse is out of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.
On every tick I retrieve the mouse position with WinAPI's

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);
```

And then check in within borders of the window manually.